# Skype mystatus alternative

Tags: json, xml, skype

It seems like Skype dropped the http://mystatus.skype.com/skypename.xml feed. Since the beginning of May it's always "offline". 
Does anybody know a simple alternative to create a custom Button?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible, once they said:

*"We haven't actively supported these buttons for some time, as their accuracy has deteriorated. For example, someone’s status is not always reflected accurately (especially when they are on a mobile device). We are now removing their functionality entirely."*

Look at:
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA605/how-do-i-set-up-the-skype-button-to-show-my-status-on-the-web-in-skype-for-windows-desktop